# How can I end this BST loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am solving a BST algorithm given a number n, I need to return the highest value that is less than n. Unfortunately, once I find the answer. My code does not return it but continues to loop. What am I missing? Thanks.

```
class Node:

# Constructor to create a new node
  def __init__(self, key):
      self.key = key
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.parent = None

# A binary search tree 
class BinarySearchTree:

  # Constructor to create a new BST
  def __init__(self):
      self.root = None

  def find_largest_smaller_key(self, num):
      largest = 0

      while self.root:

        if self.root.key < num and self.root.key > largest:
            largest = self.root.key

        if self.root.right:
          if self.root.right.key < num and self.root.right.key > largest:
            self.root = self.root.right

        if self.root.left:
            if self.root.left.key < num and self.root.left.key > largest:
              largest = self.root.left.key
              self.root = self.root.left
      return largest
```

Comment: Please use a consistent indentation scheme; it will make your code easier to read than if you use 4 spaces for some levels and 2 for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool algorithm.

Think about what will happen when there is no left or right anymore:

This might happen once, but no longer cause then largest == self.root.key therefore not in here

```
 if self.root.key < num and self.root.key > largest:
            largest = self.root.key
```

This will not happen

```
if self.root.right:
```

Neither will this

```
if self.root.left:
```

but

self.root still is true, so

```
  while self.root:
```

Will keep runnin g forevere

Comment: wow, awesome thanks. I can't believe I forgot to add an else statement.